# Python Error 13

Tags: python, permissions

We have a computer here at the office that is getting a permission error when we run "pip install opencv-python" from a powershell cmd window.

I tested this on a separate computer and it installed without a hitch. I tried this same command on the problem machine from a domain admin login and get the same permission issue.

Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Error:

```
PS C:\users> pip install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
Using cached opencv_python-3.2.0.6-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.11.3 (from opencv-python)
Using cached numpy-1.12.1-cp36-none-win32.whl
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
hashes=hashes
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 663, in unpack_http_url
unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 499, in unzip_file
fp = open(fn, 'wb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\%username&\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-g1uoy1vs\\numpy\\numpy/distutils/mingw/gfortran_vs2003_hack.c'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the root permission:

```
sudo pip install opencv-python
```

now it should work

Comment: It's on a windows machine so SUDO doesn't work because it says "sudo : The term 'sudo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: Can you run cmd as admin?

Comment: Guess I forgot to add the fact that we ran Powershell as an administrator. that's the first thing I did

Comment: @Matt see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355073/upgrading-numpy-fails-with-permission-denied-error), it should resolve your issue