# Numpy Installtion on Azure App Service WebApp - [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, pandas, azure, numpy, azure-web-app-service

I've pandas as a dependency to read some excel files in my webapp. Everything was fine until I started a new deployment today. The app service has shown that pandas has numpy as dependency(yes I agree it has) and downloads the 1.14.2 version of numpy to install and then the installation fails with the below error. I tried providing a wheel file in the wheelhouse and specifying the numpy version in requirements is giving me the same error.

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   'D:\home\python364x64\Lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.BNVRK7633HSX7YVO2TADGR4A5KEKXJAW.gfortran-win_amd64.dll'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after so many days. Since numpy is already installed and the web app is currently being served, Azure app service did not allow any update to the existing numpy library in the Site Extensions. I had to stop the webapp and try the deployment again which worked. Thanks to the SO post -
[Upgrading numpy fails with "Permission denied" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355073/upgrading-numpy-fails-with-permission-denied-error/37682081)